# Can a foreigner be charged for solicitation in another state?

Tags: united-states

if a foreigner who doesn’t live in the states, paid for prostitute services in new york 1 year ago and wasn’t caught or anything like that but if for some reason, the police found out about it somehow.. The statute of limitations is 2 years in New York. And if the foreginer were to visit Hawaii in half a year from now or 1.5 years from the date of solicitation, can he be charged in Hawaii? It is a different state from New York but it is still within NY’s 2 years statute of limitation.. what do u think are the chances?

Answer (score 2):

You can be charged for a crime until the statute of limitations has expired.  If it was not a federal crime then your concern would be [interstate extradition](http://www.shestokas.com/general-law/interstate-extradition-in-the-united-states/) (a.k.a. *rendition*).  If the crime was committed in another state then if you are charged and a warrant is issued for your arrest it depends on how serious the crime was.  Even if local police find that you are a fugitive, it is up to the state in which you were charged to decide whether they will pay the costs to retrieve you.  If they won't, then the state in which you are found will not detain you further on that warrant.

Comment: Technically they can also be extradited from a different country with which the US has an extradition treaty.

Comment: @Dale However, extradition treaties are more restrictive than interstate rendition.

Answer (score 2):

Tangential to your question but the statute of limitations limits the time within which legal proceedings may be initiated.

If an arrest warrant were issued within time then the person could be prosecuted at any time before they died.